# Is libc++ backward compatible with older versions?

Tags: clang, clang++, libc++

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have installed [libc++-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libc++-dev) (and ABI) package which is [libc++-6.0-2](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/index.html).

However, now I have to use CLang 11, which requires a newer version of libc++ for better support to C++17, so I need to install [libc++-11-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libc++-11-dev), which is a different package and will replace my older.

My question is, how do I know if libc++ is backward compatible? I have hundreds of projects built and I don't want to rebuild all again.

I can't find a clear information about it in [libcxx-11 documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Newer versions of the libc++ dylib have new features, but it is intended that the dylib is compatible going forward.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: I was looking for info about Windows, do you happen to know if new dlls (e.g. `libc++.dll`) are compatible with old programs in the same way?